# Invalid numeric input error in delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, text-files, pascal

I have a program to read list of competitors their scores from a text file:

```
var
  competition : TextFile;
  number : byte;
  name : array of string;
  score : array of array of byte;
  j : byte;
  i : byte;

begin
  AssignFile(competition, 'korcule.txt');
  Reset(competition);
  ReadLn(competition, number);
  SetLength(name, number);
  SetLength(score, number, 4);
  for i := 0 to number - 1 do begin
    ReadLn(competition, name[i]);
    j := 0;
    While not EoLn(competition) do begin
      Read(competition, score[i, j]);
      inc(j);
    end;
  end;
  ReadLn;
  CloseFile(competition);
end.
```

First line of the text file is number of competitors, then name and after name are the scores of actual people.

```
5
John Smith
1 8 4 6
Marc Zuckerberg
4 6 7 1
Bill Gates
3 8 4 1
Johnny Rapid
9 9 2 7
Phillip Lauren
4 7 3 1
```

I need to read the scores individually in multidimensional array like this myarray[1] = 1, myarray[2] = 8 and so on. Problem is that my code always gives me an error 'invalid numeric input'. What is the problem ??

Comment: *invalid numeric input

Comment: Why are you still using legacy IO? Personally, I'd read it line by line, and then split the line with multiple values. Why do you ask questions, and not accept answers?

Comment: The only reason these IO tools still exist in Delphi is for backwards compatibility with very old versions of Delphi.

Comment: @JerryDodge, there is also console IO to support. Pity that they did not fix  thread safety as is done in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `readln` after the `while` loop.

At the end of the while loop, you've reached the end of the line, but you haven't yet moved to the next line.

Also, your final `readln` is reading from `stdin` rather than from the text file.